# Please change the default text for title textbox of the question

Tags: bug, status-declined, asking

Its still showing:--

```
 what's your programming question? be specific.
```

On a gaming site programming question.... :-)[image]

Comment: Does it show that as soon as the page loads? On my screen, it has grey text within the box that reads correctly "what's your question? be specific." The only thing that appears in a list underneath like that are questions I've asked before or other things I've used as a title.

Comment: That's not the watermark, that's autocomplete. When the page first loads, as Pure said, it should say "what's your question?..." in the textbox. If you highlight the autocomplete entry and hit delete, it will get rid of it.

Comment: piemesons, I'm afraid the only fix is clearing your form history :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, that is not from us, that's from your browser's autocomplete -- I don't see that in Chrome or Firefox though so it must be a Safari quirk.

Comment: The provided screenshot is of Firefox. Not Safari.

Comment: @less regardless, not our bug

Comment: Of course it isn't. I was merely offering a correction.

Comment: @LessPop it's also not something the SE team can fix :)